# Enumeration Centering

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I would like to center things when I am doing enumerations.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{istgame}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{max}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{min}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
            [circle]{1.2cm}
            %\xtShowTerminalNodes[box node, minimum size = 1cm]
            \def\distFactor{20};
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
            \setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
            \istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
            \istb[blue, ->-] \istb \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$-0.5$}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
            \istb{}{2} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
            \istb{}{1} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
            \istb{}{0} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(6)(2-2)[min]<center, red>{$-1$}
            \istb{}{-1} \istb{}{0} \endist
        \end{istgame}
    \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =*, label = (\alph*)]
        \item $\hphantom{a}$ \vspace{-0.75cm}\newline   
        \begin{center}
            \begin{istgame}
                \setistNewNodeStyle{max}
                [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
                \setistNewNodeStyle{min}
                [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
                \setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
                [circle]{1.2cm}
                %\xtShowTerminalNodes[box node, minimum size = 1cm]
                \def\distFactor{20};
                \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
                \setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
                \istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
                \istb[blue, ->-] \istb \endist
                \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
                \istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
                \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
                \istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$-0.5$}
                \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
                \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
                \istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
                \istb{}{2} \istb{}{2} \endist
                \istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
                \istb{}{1} \istb{}{2} \endist
                \istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
                \istb{}{0} \istb{}{2} \endist
                \istroot(6)(2-2)[min]<center, red>{$-1$}
                \istb{}{-1} \istb{}{0} \endist
            \end{istgame}
        \end{center}
        $$a = b$$
    \end{enumerate}
    $$a = b$$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I realized that whenever I place a centered object (e.g. `$$ a = b $$`, `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`, etc.), the object will always be centered with respect to the enumeration and the right side of the page, when I actually want it to be centered about the horizontal midway point of the page (i.e. x = 4.25 inches from the left on an 8.5 by 11 inch paper). How much does the `enumeration` and `itemize` shift the centered object, and how can one compensate for that? I know `adjustwidth` can do the job, it's just the matter of finding the exact value of how much the enumeration shifts the centered object.

Comment: I do not understand why you need an enumeration here ? Is it only for the `(a)` mark ? It feels like you want to use the functionalities of e.g the `subcaption` package

Comment: No, I mean, I am using the enumeration for the sake of showing that the centered objects are not actually in the center.

Comment: Hmm, the centering is performed in terms of the current `\textwidth` and indentation, so it seems normal to me. If you are in an indented environment, you are centered with respect to this indentation

Comment: I a more general fashion, you should use `figure` environments to surround your graphic objects

Comment: Oh ok, I was wondering if I can adjust the centering such that the indentation has no effect on the centered object’s position

Comment: Also, regarding `figure`, the indentation effect is the same. What kind of problems will happen if one doesn’t put the `figure` environment around the graphic?

Comment: That is the purpose of the floating environments such as `figure` or `tables` see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: No specic problem is to be expected I guess, except that `figure` will provide a better positioning of these objects and will facilitate cross-referencing through the document.

Comment: Oh ok, let me try `figure`ing it

Comment: @BambOo I used the `\begin{figure}[H]` environment on the graphics, it worked. However, it adds a little bit of extra white vertical space on the bottom of the figure. How can one get rid of the extra white space (not an important question, though)? More importantly, how to center align the equation without the indentation effect?

Comment: Probably `\begin{equation*} .. \begin{equation*}`

Comment: @BambOo that didn't work. In fact, `\begin{equation*} a = b \begin{equation*}` had the same result as `$$a=b$$`.

Comment: The thing is that if you enumerate somenthing there should be a graphical block related to the enumeration hence the indentation. If you do not want an indentation, the question is, do you really need an enumeration ?

Comment: @BambOo Yes, I would want to, because if I were to do homework that involves subproblems, then that would be need to be in the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Well, when you say "subproblem" I understand sectionning. In general IMHO, people tend to not use enumerations for sectioning. That is the exact purpose of `\section, \subsection ... ` This way you do not modify indentation of the content and you get easier cross referencing in the document.

Comment: I mean, my teachers do enumerations when writing math hw problems so...

Comment: I see, you could tell them to improve their format ^^ (I'm joking), don't they have indents in their enumerations ?

Comment: Yes, they do have indents on their enumerations.

Comment: Well then I would not be to much worried about yours